# Google Apps Script If Statement Matches Cell Value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a query regarding Google App Script and If Statements.

I have pushed data from my Ads account to a Google sheet. I then want multiple sheets to pull specific data from that. So I am trying to make one sheet the source of all data. I can then select parts of the data I need for each of my report.

The main one is to get the range where the day of the week == today.

I have tried doing this by adding a check variable which is then passed into a for loop checking if the day == the dayName variable.

I am currently getting an execution issue with it timing out. This is leading me to believe I have an issue with the way I have done this.

The data set is 21k rows:
A is date, B is day of week, C is campaign and so on up to column I.

I'm still very new to the scripting game and any help is truly appreciated.

The reason I am looking to do it this way is because I seriously struggled to include a where statement within ads script to filter by DayOfWeek. I then thought this may an alternate solution.

Thanks,
Liam

```
function myFunction() {

 //This is the days of the week for the today lookup
 var days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

 //This is today's date
 var end = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);

 //This supplies the current day of week
 var dow = new Date(end);
 var dayName = days[dow.getDay()];

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID'); //ID of the sheet

 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('googleData'); //Sheet name

 var range = ss.getRange('A1:I'); //The range to copy
 var check = ss.getRange('B2:B').getValues(); The range to if statement against
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID'); //destination sheet ID

 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('usedData'); //Destination sheet name

  for (var i=0;i<check.length; i++) {
   if(check[i]==dayName) { 
      ts.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is to find all rows that match the current day of week and copy to userData.  Try this.

```
function myFunction() {
  try {
    // javascript getDay starts with Sunday
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var today = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek = days[today.getDay()];
    // Do you need id or just active spreadsheet?
    var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spread.getSheetByName("googleData");
    // Get all data columns A thru I
    var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),9).getValues();
    // results will become a 2D array to use setValues
    var results = [];
    for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
      // Day of week in column B
      if( data[i][1] === dayOfWeek ) results.push(data[i]);
    }
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("usedData");
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.getRange(1,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reply. I used sheet ID as I placed this script in the used data file so it pulls from the ID. Should I attach it to the Google data instead?

Comment: Just to add, I have just tested both methods and the script is not firing but also not throwing an error.

Comment: The execution log shows this:

[18-11-21 15:46:58:454 GMT] Logger.log([ReferenceError: "result" is not defined., []]) [0 seconds]
[18-11-21 15:46:58:455 GMT] Execution succeeded [2.282 seconds total runtime]

Comment: Oops typo I put result.push() it should have been results.push()

Comment: Awesome and such a silly thing I should have noticed. I just tested and it pushed through the correct data. 

I noticed that it doesn't overwrite the whole sheet. I had more rows of data and it only replaced the rows it covered. Should it replace all the rows? if not I can have a look into how to get that to work. 

Trying to learn as much as possible and really appreciate the help given.

Comment: I'm not sure what you ultimately want.  If when you run the script all old userData should be deleted and replaced with the new data if so I've included a sheet.clear() above.  And if this does resolve your question, please mark as answered.  Thanks.

Comment: No that is perfect thank you. This will help me when doing my other scripts massively, so thank you.