# Google Sheets Scripts, IF date of a cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I ve been getting some issues trying to use IF statement using items on the sheets as answers, mostly i been trying either using as firt statement a string directly or using another cell of the sheets with the statement comparing to the one i ve been trying to detect with out any results. Mostly my objective would be to, with a daly trigger, use an IF statement to detect every day if the date of today is the same as a date marked on a cell, my only current solution is and only thing is to make it detect if a cell is empty or not, so i just been using google Formulas that do the detect of the date, and if True make it empty, and if not make something appear

Here are some of the tests I ve been trying

Test 1:

```
var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetName");
else if (Sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue() == "2/2/2020"){}
```

(cell A1=2/2/2020)

Test 2:

```
var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetName");
else if (Sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue() == Sheet.getRange(1, 2).getValue()){}
```

(cell A1=2/2/2020)
(cell B1=2/2/2020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

This first one gets the values, formats them to a date format, and then compares them

```
function myFunction() {
  var tz = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var aVal = Utilities.formatDate(data[0][0],tz,'MM/dd/YYYY');
  var bVal = Utilities.formatDate(data[0][1],tz,'MM/dd/YYYY');
  
  Logger.log([aVal,bVal])

  if(aVal == bVal) {
  
    //do something
    
  }

}
```

This second section gets the display values and compares them.  The first solution compares the date values while this second solution compares the dates as a string.  Good luck!

```
function myFunction1() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  
  var aVal = data[0][0]
  var bVal = data[0][1]
  
  Logger.log([aVal,bVal])

  if(aVal == bVal) {
  
    //do something
    
  }

}
```

Comment: The first one was a little bit buggy, it was a bit confusing with the cells for some reason, and when i took a date, when checking it with the debug it was reducing the date that appeared by one for some reason.

The second one worked perfectly.

Would it also be posible too, to make it detect if it is a certain day of the week, or if it is the first day of the month for example?

Comment: Check out both of these questions/answers for some tips on how to get the day of the week and first/last of the month.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414943/google-apps-script-if-statement-matches-cell-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64126551/how-to-get-the-1st-date-and-last-date-of-the-current-week-as-well-as-month-in-th/64129806#64129806